# Typeorm ManyToMany JOIN 3 tables

Tags: typeorm

I have this query

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
LEFT JOIN USER_GROUPS
ON USER_GROUPS.USER_ID = USERS.USER_ID
LEFT JOIN GROUPS_ROLES
ON GROUPS_ROLES.GROUP_ID = USER_GROUPS.GROUP_ID
LEFT JOIN ROLES
ON ROLES.ROLE_ID = GROUPS_ROLES.ROLE_ID;
```

And I want to describe his relation ManyToMany in Entity
Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

Of course it's, just describe it smth like that:

```js
@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @ManyToMany(type => Group)
    @JoinTable()
    groups: Group[];
}

@Entity()
export class Group {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @ManyToMany(type => Role)
    @JoinTable()
    roles: Role[];
}

@Entity()
export class Role {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

}
```

And that's it. It should works.

Comment: Yes, It's work, but, I want roles in User. In this way I should write user.groups.map(group => group.roles); but I want just user.roles

Comment: Then add roles to User, the same way as it's in Group.